# Why isn't my AngularJS code working? (Just begining)

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015

I am only a few days into AngularJS, and have been having trouble trying to print out this simple message. I have 2 files, one is "index.html" and the other is "app.js". They are mind-numbingly simple:

```
<!--index.html:-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Testing Angular</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="maryCtrl">
        <p>{{mary}}</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<<!--end of index-->


//app.js:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('maryCtrl', function ($scope) {

 $scope.mary = 'had a little lamb.';

});

//end of app.js
```

The output on the page should be "had a little lamb." but I get "{{mary}}" instead. What really pisses me off is that I have a separate computer where it works just fine. I figure I must have a character wrong or am missing an extension, but I find that hard to believe since I just downloaded Visual Studio 2015 on this machine which has AngularJS and Angular-intellisense pre-loaded. Any help or criticism would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code, expect you missed to add `angular.js` file reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a reference to the angular.js code.
make sure it is at the top of your script references.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

The link I provided is for a copy of the code that is hosted on a Google CDN. There are tons of benefits for using the CDN as opposed to having a local copy of angular.js on your computer (as long as you aren't trying to test your code offline).

You can find the CDN link on angularjs.org; Just click on the big blue download button and you will see options for obtaining the most recent version or legacy versions of angular.js

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

as @Pankaj Parkar commented, you should have angular.js file referenced before your app.js file:

```
 <!--index.html:-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Testing Angular</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="maryCtrl">
        <p>{{mary}}</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<<!--end of index-->


//app.js:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('maryCtrl', function ($scope) {

 $scope.mary = 'had a little lamb.';

});

//end of app.js
```

you can download it from https://github.com/angular/angular.js